# OAuth 2.0 Playground - Alert API not working

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to access the alerts api through the oAuth2.0 login flow from my React application.

The alert API scope

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts

returns

> **Error 400: invalid_scope**

when trying to login through my local application, as well as through the oAuth playground.

Is there any different way I can authenticate to use the alerts api scope?

I've verified that my local application does work when using other scopes.

Comment: I have verified that it does no work and I have pinged the Oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

That api requires that you use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/guides/auth#create_a_service_account)  that is the only valid authorization form for this api.

The Oauth playground uses Oauth2 to authorize so its not going to work with that api.